# High precision evaluation of the series $\sum_{n=3}^\infty (-1)^n (1-n^{1/n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation, euler-maclaurin

This series converges conditionally, but it's quite slow. I would like to find its value with high accuracy:

$$S=\sum_{n=3}^\infty (-1)^n (1-n^{1/n})$$

Wolfram Alpha gives $S \approx 0.226354\ldots$.

Since the terms decrease monotonely in absolute value, we can apply an approximate estimation:

$$S_N= \sum_{n=3}^{N-1} (-1)^n (1-n^{1/n})+ \frac{1}{2} (-1)^N (1-N^{1/N})$$

$$S_{100}=0.22644\ldots$$

$$S_{101}=0.22626\ldots$$

$$\frac{S_{100}+S_{101}}{2} =0.22635473854439942\ldots$$

Another way could be to transform the series, for example:

$$n^{1/n}=\exp \frac{\log n}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\log^k n}{n^k k!}$$

Which gives us (assuming we are allowed to change the order of summation):

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{n=3}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{\log^k n}{n^k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{S_k}{k!}$$

The inner series $S_k>0$ can be expressed in terms of repeated derivatives of the zeta function, which don't have a closed form for $k \geq 2$, but the series can still be evaluated numerically with high accuracy.

---

**Note**

$$S_1=\frac{\log 2}{2} (1+\log 2-2\gamma)$$

For $k \geq 2$ we can easily write:

$$S_k=\sum_{q=1}^\infty \frac{\log^k (2q+1)}{(2q+1)^k}-\sum_{q=2}^\infty \frac{\log^k (2q)}{(2q)^k}$$

Both the series converge absolutely and can be easily approximated by Euler-Maclaurin summation with all the integrals and derivatives expressed in closed form (obviously for large $k$ it becomes unwieldy).

---

Evaluating the series up to $S_6$ we obtain:

$$S > 0.2263538 \ldots$$

Still not that good.

Finally, we could use Euler-Maclaurin, but I'm not sure how to apply it in this case, especially how to deal with the integral.

Comment: Maybe this helps:https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/366628?p_p_auth=27N1LFUd

Comment: The $n$th term of this alternating series approximates $(-1)^{n+1}n^{-1}\ln n$. I'm not sure whether the Shanks transformation works in view of the $\ln n$ factor, but I'm sure something similar would.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk, I did not expect this series to be quite that popular, thank you for the link. It's truly a work of years

Comment: Is it that the sequence {n^(1/n)} is monotone from n>=3, that you chose to start at 3?

Comment: @MarvinRayBurns, yes, this is the reason

Comment: So now that you have 5,000,000 digits at my Wolfram Community post, you can save $m$ and your value is $$sqrt(2)-1-m$$.

Comment: @MarvinRayBurns, I was very impressed by the amount of work presented there. I'm not really interested in the value, I'm interested in the methods, so I'm still studying your post

Comment: I started my work on MRB with only  high school education. It was my hope that more educated people will add to it.

Comment: It seems that, every day, someone comes up with a new piece of random math that will instantly die for a lack of general interest. 

It looks like I got very lucky with MRB. A lot of people like you and Richard Crandall have taken note of its existence and properties!!!!!

Comment: @YuriyS, Speaking of sqrt(2)-1 and MRB, have you come up with the digits .316453098860696332954691288864309266518251...? See  https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/515865?sortMsg=Replies .

Answer (score 3):

Using [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) you can get a thousand decimal digits using

```
default(realprecision,10^3); c=sumalt(n=3, (-1)^n*(1-n^(1./n)));
```

in under 30 seconds. It takes much longer for more digits. It Seems to be an
$O(n^3)$ time algorithm where $n$ is the number of digits.

In case you are interested,
the documentation for PARI/GP describes the algorithms used for the summation
of alternating series. Also, the entire source code is under the GPL license.
Here is a brief documentation excerpt.

> `sumalt(X = a,expr,{flag = 0}):`
>
> Numerical summation of the series `expr`, which should be an alternating
>   series $(-1)^k a_k,\,$ the formal variable `X` starting at `a.`  Use an
>   algorithm of Cohen, Villegas and Zagier (Experiment. Math. 9 (2000), no.
>   1, 3--12).

The work mentioned here seems to be available from a [Project Euclid
link](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.em/1046889587).
You may also be interested in the
[OEIS sequence A037077](https://oeis.org/A037077)

> Decimal expansion of upper limit of - 1^(1/1) + 2^(1/2) - 3^(1/3) + ...

authored by Marvin Ray Burns for which the constant is named (MRB constant).

Comment: Cohen, Villegas and Zagier's paper "Convergence acceleration of alternating series" should be available [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.em/1046889587). Cheers,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Thanks for that link!

Answer (score 1):

*Hints.*

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=3}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}(\sqrt[n]{n}-1) = \sqrt{2}-1 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)^k $

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)^k |_{k=1} = \frac{\ln 2}{2}(\ln 2~-2\gamma) $

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)^k |_{k=2} = \frac{1}{2}\zeta’’(2) + \frac{\pi^2\ln 2}{12}(\ln 2 + 2\gamma + 2 \ln\pi~ – 24\ln A)$

$\hspace{7cm}$ where $A$ is the Glaisher-Kinkelin constant

I have *no* proof for the following formula:

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)^k |_{k\geq 3} = \sum\limits_{j=0}^k a_{k,j}(\ln 2)^{k-j}\zeta^{(j)}(k)$

with  $\enspace\displaystyle a_{k,j}|_{0\leq j\leq k-1}=\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{2^{k-1}}\binom k j\enspace$ 
and   $\enspace\displaystyle a_{k,k} = (-1)^k\frac{2^{k-1}-1}{2^{k-1}}$

Informations about $~\zeta^{(j)}(k)~$ please see e.g. [here](https://digitalcommons.wku.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=27&ved=2ahUKEwjMx5SuxbnjAhVLLpoKHcBPBWo4FBAWMAZ6BAgAEAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdigitalcommons.wku.edu%2Fcgi%2Fviewcontent.cgi%3Farticle%3D2093%26context%3Dtheses&usg=AOvVaw0gQx0dl_Nw4esC2IQc0LEo&httpsredir=1&article=2093&context=theses) , formulas (11)+(16)+(19).